# RIErr0035: Failed to get Device ID in MPlab 8 after using MPlabX

Tags: pic, mplab, pic32

I used MPlab X for a new project and it worked. After I was finished I had to work on a MPlab 8 project.  I first ran the MPlab driver switcher to tell it I was now using MPlab 8. I then ran MPlab 8, loaded my project and connected my REALICE programmer/debugger. I got a RIErr0035: Failed to get Device ID. It had worked before. I tried a PICKIT 3 and get the same error. I tried a different prolect and it got the same error. All of the projects and programmers worked before I used MPlab X for  a new project. I have also rebooted my PC. What can I do to fix this issue so I can work on my MPlab 8 projects again?

Comment: You may need to use the driver switcher, [see here for details](https://microchip.wikidot.com/mplabx:switching-usb-drivers).

Comment: I have already used the device switcher and it made no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

This post is rather old but I had exactly the same problem with `2 RealIce` and so was using a `Pickit3` for old projects with `Mplab8`.

Already searched and found no solution till this:

1. Go to `Debugger (or Programmer) > Settings Configuration`;
2. select `Manual Download`;
3. A file named `RIFW_012890.jam` (or similar) from directory `Michrochip/MPLAB IDE/REAL ICE` will be proposed. Select it, wait 1 minute, and miracle, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. After wasting 2 hours this error, the "Manual Download" suggestion ([by Lunasix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35479942/)) finally worked.

My suggestion for all:  Abandon MicroChip MCU and DevTools completely, and switch to something that works properly, like ST Micro.

Answer (score 0):

dennis 
there are three reason which can create error that Failed to get device id

1. PGC/PGD PIN ARE SWAPPED.
2. VCAP/VDDCORE CAPCITOR ARE NOT PPOPER.
3. Microcontroller got damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to program the pic 12f629 with pickit3

After several hours on the Internet and testing locally, the solution was to reduce the voltage level from Pickit USB supply (pickit 3 settings>power)!

Remember that solution in other products with pickit 2